# How to copy a range of data to another google sheet using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

**Source:**
[image]

**Destination:**
[image]

Hi everyone,

I have 2 google sheets, `Source` & `Destination`. I want to copy a range of data from Source sheet to Destination sheet by using google apps script. So the data should appear at the last row of the Destination sheet. This is my code:

```
function copyInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Source");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Destination");

  // get source range
  var source = copySheet.getRange(3,1,1,10);
  // get destination range
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,10);

  // copy values to destination range
  source.copyTo(destination);

}
```

Seems like the script only allow me to do the copying within one google sheet (different tab) instead of 2 different google sheet. May I know how should I modified it so that the script able to find my destination google sheet and paste the data at the last row? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**
[image]

I tried to use `onEdit` to triggered the script, however it seems like not working. Below is my script:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  if (e.range.columnStart == 11 && e.range.rowStart == 3){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const id ='1r5Hygl5ysahMi6DQ3duDR5L8c4aGX_0CJba7lXxnejw';
    var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var pasteSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    
    if (e.value == 'Submit'){
      var source = copySheet.getRange(3,1,1,10);
      const values = source.getValues();
      var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,10);
      destination.setValues(values);
    }
  }
}
```

Source:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jnOvE-Dc7y9o7GsgN9fjOXZWlUCwiJayugX5q4Y3CA0/edit#gid=0

Destination:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r5Hygl5ysahMi6DQ3duDR5L8c4aGX_0CJba7lXxnejw/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use methods [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

```js
const id ='ID of paste Spreadsheet here';
var pasteSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName("Destination");
var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,10);
const values = source.getValues();
destination.setValues(values);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried to apply your method in the `onEdit` function in order to triggered the script, however, it doesn't work, may I know where did I did wrong? I edited my question with modified script

Comment: Could you provide the [execution result](https://script.google.com/home/executions) of `onEdit`? I think your code has no problem.

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined`, this is the error that I get, I attached my google sheets in my question as well.

Comment: It seems simple trigger (`onEdit`) does not allow you to refer to other spreadsheet. Instead, you need to change the trigger name (for example `_onEdit(e)`) and [create an onEdit yourself](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

Comment: Do you mean putting the `copyInfo` into the `onEdit` function? I tried but not working either

Comment: No, change function name `onEdit` to `_onEdit`, [create a new trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually), to run: `_onEdit`, event source: From spreadsheet, event type: On edit

Answer (score 0):

The method `getSheetByName` is used to define a sheet within a spreadsheet. To define a specific spreadsheet, you should use `openById` and associate the spreadhseet ID ([https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/%7Bspreadsheet) ID}/edit).

Define your source sheet as:

```
var copysheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('enter id for Source').getSheetByName('Sheet 1')
```

Define your destination sheet as:

```
var pastesheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('enter id for Destination').getSheetByName('Sheet 1')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your goal is the following:

```js
/* Every time a user sets the value of cell K3 in source spreadsheet
   to "submit". Copy all the values of row 3 and paste them into the
   destination sheet under the last row. Then delete the source values 
   and set the value of K3 to "Clear" again. */
```

You need a installed trigger and a function to copy the values when triggered. So lets do that step by step.

#### Example:

1. First lets create a script that is bound to your source SS. Let's edit your `copyInfo()` function so that it takes the destination spreadsheet Id as parameter.

```js
function copyTo(destinationSSId) {
    // Open source SS at tab named "Source"
    let copySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Source");
    // Open destination SS at tab named "Destination"
    let pasteSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSSId).getSheetByName("Destination");
    // Get source values
    let sourceValues = copySheet.getRange(3, 1, 1, 10).getValues();
    // Set values to destination range
    pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 10).setValues(sourceValues);
    // Log the pasted values from the last row
    console.log("Last row pasted: " + pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, 10).getValues()[0]);
}
```

2. Make a function to clear the source values and reset the "form".

```js
function clearSubmission() {
    let copySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Source");
    copySheet.getRange(3, 1, 1, 10).clearContent()
    copySheet.getRange(3, 11, 1, 1).setValue("Clear");
    console.log("Source submitted and cleared.")
}
```

3. Set up the function to trigger.

```js
function myTriggeredFunction(e) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e.range), e.value)
    if (e.range.columnStart == 11 && e.range.rowStart == 3) {
        if (e.value == 'Submit') {
            let destinationSSId = '{YOUR DESTINATION SS ID}';
            copyTo(destinationSSId);
            clearSubmission();
        }
    }
}
```

4. Install the trigger as "From spreadsheet - On edit" to run the function `myTriggeredFunction` by going to the "Triggers" tab in your project.